# Override datagridview class

Tags: c#

I want to override the datagridview class like override bool ProcessDialogKey and ProcessDataGridViewKey. 
in which form should i write this code to work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by which form you should use, but you can extend a DataGridView in a class, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyTest
{
    class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
    {

        protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData) {
            // Your implementation here.
        }

        protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e) {
            // Your implementation here.
        }
    }
}
```

This code create a new class, `MyDataGridView` which inherits from the standard Winform `DataGridView` class.  You can read more about inheritance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: i mean i am using a datagridview in a form.should this code be in tht form or how can one make a reference of this class if it exists outside.

Comment: how to refer to this class in our form?

Comment: Create this class and use it in your form

Comment: You can find the datagrid view definition in designer.cs of form and change its declaration to MyDataGridView

Comment: The easiest would be to create the class (your control) in the same project as your form.  The control should then appear in the Toolbox from which you can add it to your form.  You can always reference the control as you would any other class (`var myDataGridView = new MyDataGridView();`).